# Using the same template name multiple times with Flask and Jinja2

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a Flask project with the following structure:

```
├── config.py
├── errors
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── handlers.py
│   └── templates
│       ├── errors
│       │   ├── 403.html
│       │   ├── 404.html
│       │   └── 500.html
│       └── default_layout.html
├── home
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── routes.py
│   └── templates
│       ├── about
│       │   └── general.html
│       └── default_layout.html
├── static
│   └── style.css
└── templates
    └── default_layout.html
```

My app contains two blueprints: errors and home.

Is there a way for template files in my blueprints to extend multiple template files with the same filename? I have the following which results in an exception:

1) app/errors/templates/errors/403.html:

```
{% extends 'default_layout.html' %}
{% block error_content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <h1>404 error</h1>
        <p>{{ error }}</p>
    </div>
{% endblock error_content %}
```

2) app/errors/templates/default_layout.html:

```
{% extends 'default_layout.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <h1>NESTED BLOCK</h1>
        {% block error_content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

3) app/templates/default_layer.html:

```
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
```

I want the `default_layout.html` referenced in 1) to refer to 2) and the `default_layout.html` referenced in 2) to refer to 3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to further nest templates using the name of the blueprint as a scope. E.g.,

```
errors/templates/default_layout.html
```

would become

```
errors/templates/errors/default_layout.html
```

And using it would become `{% extends "errors/default_layout.html" %}`